# Is this map uniformly continuous? continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $s$ denote the metric space of all sequences of complex numbers with the metric 
$$d(x,y) \colon= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} \frac{\vert \xi_j(x) - \xi_j(y)\vert}{1+\vert \xi_j(x) - \xi_j(y) \vert} $$ 
for all $x, y \in s$. Here $\xi_j(x)$ denotes the $j$-th term of $x$.

Let $k$ be a fixed natural number. Then is the map $T_k \colon s \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by 
$$T_k x \colon= \xi_k(x) \qquad \mbox{ for all } x \in s$$ 
uniformly continuous? continuous?

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some context, such as where the problem comes from or why you're interested in it. Even more so because you picked "widely applicable" as the reason for the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T_k$ is indeed uniformly continuous.

(Note: I'll also write $x_j$ instead of $\xi_j(x)$.)

First, observe that
$$
\frac{\lvert x_k - y_k \rvert}{1 + \lvert x_k - y_k \rvert}
= 2^k \cdot \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{\lvert x_k - y_k \rvert}{1 + \lvert x_k - y_k \rvert}
\leq 2^k \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} \frac{\lvert x_j - y_j \rvert}{1 + \lvert x_j - y_j \rvert}
= 2^k d(x,y).
$$
Now the function $f \colon [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ defined by $f(t) = \frac{t}{1 + t}$
is strictly increasing: $f'(t) = \frac{1}{(1+t)^2} > 0$. Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$, the condition $d(x,y) < 2^{-k} f(\epsilon)$ implies $\lvert x_k - y_k \rvert < \epsilon$, completing the proof.

---

A more abstract topological approach if we just need to prove continuity:

Given a metric space $(X,\delta)$, the function $\delta' = \frac{\delta}{1+\delta}$ is a bounded metric which generates the same topology as $\delta$. It is further seen that the corresponding product topology on $\prod_{j=1}^\infty X$ is generated by the metric $\Delta(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j} \delta'(x_j,y_j)$. So the statement that the $T_k$ are continuous is merely one manifestation of the fact that the canonical projections of product spaces are always continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just write $x_i$ for the $i$th term of $x$.

Take an open set $S\subset\mathbb{C}$, and consider $S'=T_k^{-1}(S)$.

Take $x\in S'$, and say $x_k=v\in S$, and furthermore say $B(v,r_v)\subset S$ (since $S$ is open). Then consider $B(x,\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{r_v}{1+r_v})$. Take an $x'\in B(x,\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{r_v}{1+r_v})$. Then

$$d(x,x')=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}\frac{|x_i-x'_i|}{1+|x_i-x'_i|}<\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{r_v}{1+r_v}$$

So that in particular

$$\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{|x_k-x'_k|}{1+|x_k-x'_k|}=\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{|v-x'_k|}{1+|v-x'_k|}<\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{r_v}{1+r_v}$$

So
$$\frac{|v-x'_k|}{1+|v-x'_k|}<\frac{r_v}{1+r_v}$$

From which we find, after some manipulations

$$|v-x'_k|<r_v$$

Which means that $x'_k\in B(v,r_v)\subset S$, so that $x'\in S'$, which means $ B(x,\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{r_v}{1+r_v})\subset S'$, which means that $S'$ is open, and so the inverse image of any open set is open, so $T_k$ is continuous.